# libsepol.check_assertions: 2 neverallow failures occurred Error while expanding policy

Tags: android-source, selinux

Facing issues to add new service in sepolicy.

I have followed below steps to create and register service in sepolicy

Steps 1: Create script file verifyusb.sh

> ```
> #!/system/bin/sh
>    echo "Hello USB"
>   +++some logic ++
> ```

step  2 : verifyusb.sh copied into system/bin/

> LOCAL_DEVICE_MEDIA               := device/xxx/XXX/verifyusb.sh:system/bin/verifyusb.sh

step 3 : added verifyusb.sh into init.rc
device/xxx/xxx/rcs/init.rc

on boot
exec - root root system readproc -- /system/bin/verifyusb.sh

step 4 : Created .te file 
Path : device/xxx/xxx/sepolicy/xxx/verifyusb.te

> ```
>  type verifyusb, domain;
>    type verifyusb_exec, exec_type, file_type;
>    init_daemon_domain(verifyusb)
> ```

Step 5 : register file in to device/xxx/xxx/sepolicy/xxx/file_contexts

> /system/bin/verifyusb.sh  u:object_r:verifyusb_exec:s0

Step 6 : Compiled and got this error:

[ 98% 902/918] build out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests
FAILED: out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy_tests -l out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.so                 -f out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts  -f out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts  -p out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy ) && (touch out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_tests_intermediates/sepolicy_tests )"
The following types on /system/ must be associated with the "system_file_type" attribute: verifyusb_exec

Step7 :To resolve above error added “system_file_type”  verifyusb.te file.

> ```
> type verifyusb, domain;
>   type verifyusb_exec, system_file_type, exec_type, file_type;
>   init_daemon_domain(verifyusb)
> ```

step8 : Complied source code got another error:

```
        [ 89% 818/918] build out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
```

FAILED: out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
/bin/bash -c "(ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -M -c             30 -o out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy.conf ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy-analyze out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp neverallow -w -f out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy_2.conf ||      ( echo \"\" 1>&2;         echo \"sepolicy-analyze failed. This is most likely due to the use\" 1>&2;       echo \"of an expanded attribute in a neverallow assertion. Please fix\" 1>&2;            echo \"the policy.\" 1>&2;      exit 1 ) ) && (touch out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp ) && (mv out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows )"
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 1029 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 14463 of policy.conf) violated by allow verifyusb verifyusb_exec:file { read getattr map execute entrypoint open };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 952 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 14295 of policy.conf) violated by allow verifyusb verifyusb_exec:file { execute entrypoint };
libsepol.check_assertions: 2 neverallow failures occurred
Error while expanding policy
14:43:54 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/make/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1